# python selenium how to click <a href > login button

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

```
<a href="/?redirectURL=%2F&amp;returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fpartner.yanolja.com%2Fauth%2Flogin&amp;serviceType=PC" aria-current="page" class="v-btn--active v-btn v-btn--block v-btn--depressed v-btn--router theme--light v-size--large primary" data-v-db891762="" data-v-3d48c340=""><span class="v-btn__content">
    login
  </span></a>
```

I want to click this href button using python-selenium.

First, I tried to using `find_element_by_xpath()`. But, I saw a error message that is `no such element: Unable to locate element`. Then, I used link_text, partial_link_text, and so on.

I think that message said that 'It can't find login-button' right?
How can I specify the login button?

It is my first time to using selenium, and My html knowledge is also not enough.
What should I study first?

+)

url : https://account.yanolja.bz/

I want to login and get login session this URL.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

html = urlopen('https://account.yanolja.bz/')
id = 'ID'
password = 'PW'

#options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument("headless")
#options.add_argument("window-size=1920x1080")
#options.add_argument("--log-level=3")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("c:\\chromedriver")
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.get('https://account.yanolja.bz/')

print("Title: %s\nLogin URL: %s" %(driver.title, driver.current_url))
id_elem = driver.find_element_by_name("id")
id_elem.clear()
id_elem.send_keys(id)

driver.find_element_by_name("password").clear()
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
```

Comment: First check the page for any iframes.

Comment: you should give more details, i.e the web url, full html of the page or even your source code to show exactly what you have been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this thing is not working due to `span` in your `a` tag. I have tried to give some examples but I am not sure, if you are supposed to click the `a` tag or `span`. I have tried to click the `span` in all of them.
I hope it does work. Only if you could give us what you have tried, it would be a great help to find out mistakes, if  any.

Have you tried to find the element using class. Your link is named by so many classes, Is none of them unique?
`driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "{class-name}").click()`

using x-path:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='v-btn__content']").click()`
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='{class-name}']/span[@class='v-btn__content']").click()`

if this xpath is not unique then you can use css selector
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[aria-current='page']>span.v-btn__content").click()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! ```driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='v-btn__content']").click() ``` This code works! Thank you! However, In your answer 'Most probably this thing is not working due to span in your a tag.' means that ```span``` tag blocks ```a``` tag?? Does this often happen?

Comment: This thing has also happened to me a few  times due to child tag under the `a` tag. You have to click the `child` tag rather than 'a' tag. So this might not let `find_by_link_text` work.<br> And I am just guessing this, there might be another reason.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I want to note that `span class="v-btn__content">login</span>` is not clickable. Thus, it raises an error.

Try to use this instead

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="'+url+'"]')`

Replace url with the url given in `<a href='url'>`